# If a fair die is thrown 4 times, what is the chance that at least one of the rolls is 6?

Tags: probability

At first I thought there could be $6^4$ outcomes, and if I need to throw at least one six, there are $6^3$ ways of doing it (since on the first throw I must get only one value-- that of six-- and in all the others I can get 6 values) therefore the probability should be $1/6$.

After checking the answer, I noticed that they had solved the problem with complementary probability. My question is: why was my method incorrect? What was I actually counting with my $6^3$?

Comment: I don't understand the $6^3$ calculation.  You seem to be saying that the only way to get one or more sixes is to throw a $6$ the first time, but that is clearly untrue.

Comment: @lulu what I am trying to say is that at least one throw must be a $6$, so if you saw the rolls of the die as buckets, in one bucket there can only be one value (that of six) while in the other buckets you can have all the six values of the die.

Comment: Well...ok.  But then the count is a lot harder than you are making it out to be.  You could throw the $6$ in any of four slots, so you have to multiply your $6^3$ by $4$ .  But then you have over counted (as you have counted every combination with more than one $6$ multiple times), so you have to subtract.  You can do it this way...but it's a lot easier to do it via the complement.

Answer (score 0):

What is the chance that none of the rolls is $6$? Well on each roll the chance of it not being a $6$ is $5/6$. Thus the probability of all not being $6$ is $(\frac{5}{6})^4$. Therefore the probability of at least one being a $6$ (event $A$) is 
$$P(A)=1-(\frac{5}{6})^4$$

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability that the dice will land on 6? $\frac{1}{6}$.

The rolls are independent. You desire that at least one of the rolls is $6$. Let $X \sim Binomial(n = 4, p = \frac{1}{6})$ denote the random variable mapping to the dice events. 
$$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - (\frac{5}{6})^4$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative method to the above answers, although it is much longer.

$$P(\text{at least one 6})=P(\text{exactly one 6}) +P(\text{exactly two 6's})+P(\text{exactly three 6's})+P(\text{exactly four 6's})$$

The binomial distribution is as follows:
$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$
There are $4$ trials, therefore $n = 4$.
$k$ is the number of successes.
The probability of getting one six is $\frac{1}{6}$, therefore $p=\frac{1}{6}$.

$$P(X = 1)=\binom{4}{1} (\frac{1}{6})^1 (\frac{5}{6})^{3} $$
$$P(X = 2)=\binom{4}{2} (\frac{1}{6})^2 (\frac{5}{6})^{2} $$
$$P(X = 3)=\binom{4}{3} (\frac{1}{6})^3 (\frac{5}{6})^{1} $$
$$P(X = 4)=\binom{4}{4} (\frac{1}{6})^4 (\frac{5}{6})^{0} $$
$$\therefore P(\text{at least one 6})=0.51774691358  $$

It is clear from this that the compliment method is a much better way of solving the problem.